# WP_debug errors with wp_enqueue

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, debugging

I am getting two types of errors that I don't know how to fix.

You can see the errors here:  http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/vertex/

The first type occurs twice and looks like this:

```
Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or init hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /home/admin/buzz/themes/vertex/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3587
```

I have a call in functions.php:

```
function my_init() {
if (!is_admin()) {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

The second error type is this:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$slider_height in /vertex/wp-content/themes/vertex/slider_settings.php on line 32
```

No matter where (inside or outside of if statements or both) I define these variables they are still giving me this error.

*** update

I have some other scripts enqueued in a subfolder of the theme's files, mostly used for admin area.

$path = get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/metabox/smart_meta_box/smart_meta_fields/layout-editor/';

wp_enqueue_script('mcolorpicker', $path . 'js/mColorPicker.js', array('jquery'));

wp_enqueue_style('chosen', $path . 'css/chosen.css');

wp_enqueue_style('content-layout', $path . 'css/content-layout.css');

wp_enqueue_script('jquery-json', $path . 'js/jquery.json.js', array('jquery'));

wp_enqueue_script('chosen-jquery', $path . 'js/chosen.jquery.min.js', array('jquery'));

wp_enqueue_script('content-layout-js', $path . 'js/content-layout.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-sortable'));

I think they may also be needed for front end display as well.  How would I enqueue these the right way?

- update 2

Here is the code where two of the undefined property errors occur:

[link to txt](http://www.brainbuzzmedia.com/themes/vertex/slider_settings.txt)

Comment: About the second problem, can you attach the relevant lines from your theme's files?

Comment: added a link to the php file just in a txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use the wp_enqueue_scripts action to call this function, or
>   admin_enqueue_scripts to call it on the admin side.

To load it for front end, use

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

To load it for admin, use

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts_method');
function my_admin_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

**Reference:** [**Codex**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

The second error occured because `jQuery` is not loaded.

**Update:**

If you hae any `wp_register_script(xxx)`or`wp_enqueue_style(xxx)`call in your`functions.php` or in your any `plugin file` directly then use them inside `wp_enqueue_script` handler as follows

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_register_script('xxx'); // replace the xxx with valid script name
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_style(xxx) // if you have any
}
```

Comment: I've replaced my "my_init" code with your front end and admin actions but I am still getting the same error.  Why is it saying the error is in "/wp-includes/functions.php"?  I haven't touched anything in the wp-includes folder.  Also, how is the second error from jquery not being loaded?  It is loaded in the header through that script.

Comment: My wp-includes/functions.php is the same as the one you can download from wordpress.org.  I can't tell what is actually on line 3587 because there are commented areas but nothing is related to enqueue.  Nothing even shows up if I search the file for enqueue.  My functions.php in the theme's folder isn't even close to that many lines long.

Comment: Do you have any `wp_register_script` call inside your theme's functions.php ?

Comment: Ah, I have some scripts enqueued in a subfolder, I will update the original post so I can show the code.