# Why wp_enqueue_style and wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to develop a Wordpress plugin. I have added style and script in following way

```
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'newsbox_style_and_script' );
 function newsbox_style_and_script()
 {  
   wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-style', plugins_url( '/css/bootstrap.min.css', __FILE__ ),array(),'3.0.3');
   wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-theme-style', plugins_url( '/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css', __FILE__ ),array(),'3.0.3');
   wp_enqueue_style( 'site-style', plugins_url( '/css/site.css', __FILE__ ));
  // Register the script like this for a plugin:
  wp_enqueue_script( 'newsbox-script', plugins_url( '/scripts/jquery.bootstrap.newsbox.min.js', __FILE__ ),array("jquery"), '1.0.1', true );
}
```

But it is showing the following error

Notice: wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks.

I have checked this [WP_debug errors with wp_enqueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336578/wp-debug-errors-with-wp-enqueue) . But can't solve the problem. Please tell me the solution.

UPDATE:

errors are showing for following code

```
 wp_head();?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery(".demo2").bootstrapNews({
            newsPerPage: <?php 
                            if($display_options[ 'news_per_page' ]){
                                echo $display_options[ 'news_per_page' ];
                            }
                            else{
                                echo 4;
                            }
                        ?>,
            autoplay: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            navigation: false,
            direction: 'down',
            newsTickerInterval: <?php 
                                    if($display_options[ 'news_Ticker_Interval' ]){
                                        echo $display_options[ 'news_Ticker_Interval' ];
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        echo 2500;
                                    }
                                ?>,
            onToDo: function () {
                //console.log(this);
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Would you please tell me where is the problem of this code?

Comment: are you calling the same function on another action by accident? (copy and paste mistake)

Comment: Try testing your plugin on a fresh install with one of the default themes

Comment: I am testing it by fresh install with default theme

Comment: You can check all of errors from here http://digitalsensebd.com/newsbox/